# VBA Code to Fill Series down to the next blank cell once

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do something I imagine is really simple however I am stuck on part of the code.

I need the code to look at last row with a number in in column A and fill the series down once i.e.
A20 = 0019
A21 = 0020

```
Dim LastRow As Variant
Dim LastBlankRow As Variant

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Select
LastRow2 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(LastRow & LastBlankRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I started off with this code and developed it to the one above however my range will change each time as more data is entered.

```
Range("A20").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A20:A21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A20:A21").Select
```

I imagine its something simple I have missed however I cant figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: here's a hint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/fill-a-value-down-into-blank-cells-in-a-column   Also, check out the [tour] and also [ask] and [mcve]].  And, _Welcome!_

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on `ActiveSheet`, always qualify your `Range`, `Rows` objects with your `Worksheet`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillOneDown()

Dim LastRow As Variant

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A" & LastRow).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(LastRow, "A"), .Cells(LastRow + 1, "A")), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now!

Comment: @Lydia  you're welcome , now comes your part where you mark as "Answer", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green)